# Run scrapy splash as a script

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to run a scrapy script with `splash`, as I want to scrape a `javascript` based webpage, but with no results. When I execute this script with python command, I get this error: `crochet._eventloop.TimeoutError`. In addition the print statement in parse method never printed, so I consider something is wrong with `SplashRequest`. The code that I wrote in order to implement this is that:

```
import logging

import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from crochet import setup, wait_for

setup()
# logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False

class GooglePatentsSpider(scrapy.spiders.Spider):
    name = "google_patents_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['patents.google.com']

    script = '''
        function main(splash, args)
            splash.private_mode_enabled = false
            assert(splash:go(args.url))
            splash:wait(5)
            return splash:html()
        end
    '''

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(GooglePatentsSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)
        return spider

    def item_scraped(self, item):
        return item

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(
                url=url, 
                callback = self.parse,
                endpoint='execute',
                args={
                    'lua_source': self.script
                }
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        print('from parse')
        item = {}
        
        item['status'] = 'Hello world'

        return item

@wait_for(timeout=50.0)
async def run_spider():
    """Returns all the scraped items of the provided publication number"""
    results = []

    def crawler_results(signal, sender, item, response, spider):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_scraped)
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings={
        'BOT_NAME': 'web_page_crawler',
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36',
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
        'SPLASH_URL': 'http://192.168.59.103:8050',
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
            'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
        },
        'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
        },
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
        'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
    })
    await runner.crawl(GooglePatentsSpider, start_urls=[f'https://patents.google.com/?q=CL%3dgenistein'])
    if results:
        return results[0]
    else:
        return 'This publication number cannot be retrieved'

run_spider()
```

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hits_scraper.py", line 89, in <module>
run_spider()
File "/home/shared/projects/siftlink/scrapers/.scrapers-api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crochet/_eventloop.py", line 461, in wrapper
return eventual_result.wait(timeout)
File "/home/shared/projects/siftlink/scrapers/.scrapers-api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crochet/_eventloop.py", line 196, in wait
result = self._result(timeout)
File "/home/shared/projects/siftlink/scrapers/.scrapers-api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/crochet/_eventloop.py", line 175, in _result
raise TimeoutError()
crochet._eventloop.TimeoutError
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas Just added

Comment: I got the same error when I didn't start `splash` before running code. If I run `splash` using `docker` then it has different `IP` - `172.17.0.2` - and if I use this IP in settings then code works.

Comment: I got correct IP from docker: `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' (docker ps -q)`

Comment: @furas Thank you! That worked! Even though I can not explain why I have to change the IP as when I run splash inside scrapy project and not as a script works fine.

Comment: docker works also with `'SPLASH_URL': 'http://0.0.0.0:8050'`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error when I did't start `splash` befor running code.

If I run `splash` (as `docker` image) then I also get this error because it had different `IP`
but if I use correct `IP` in `'SPLASH_URL'` then it works.

On Linux I got `IP` of running image using

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $(docker ps -q)
```

but it seems code works also with universal IP `0.0.0.0`

```
'SPLASH_URL': 'http://0.0.0.0:8050'
```